# Set Ubuntu 14.04 environment variable via PuTTY

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, putty

I need to set an environment variable for a Python package that I am intending on using. The variable needs to be:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/pmj27/software/boost1.60/lib"
```

I have tried adding this variable to a number of files: `~/.pam_environment`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` as suggested here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

However, none of that seems to have worked. If I run `printenv` upon logging out and logging in again `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not show up. Where am I going wrong?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and logging in via PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/pmj27/software/boost1.60/lib"

to ~/.bashrc (assuming you are using bash as your login shell).

Log out and then back in and see what printenv shows you.

Comment: That has not solved the problem. As mentioned I am using PuTTY. Does that use bash?

Comment: The system you are connecting to determines which shell one is running, not Putty. What is the output of. echo $0 (this current shell is stored in this environment variable).

Comment: I am sorry, it did work indeed. I missed it in the list. I will accept your answer right now.